# Login using Tastypie. Curl example

Tags: django, tastypie

https://github.com/nakule/Task-Manager/blob/master/taskmanager/api.py

How can I login using this `UserResource`? Can someone provide example with curl?

> curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data
>   '{"username":"myusername", "password":"mypass"}'
>   http://mywebsite.com/api/user/

Answer (score 0):

Usually all requests to django-tastypie starts from mentioning version `v1` of the api.
So, you were pretty close:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"username":"myusername", "password":"mypass"}' "http://mywebsite.com/api/v1/login/" -v
```

Answer (score 0):

The `login` view should've been registered under `/api/v1/users/login/` url.